# redis-cli config host and port

Tags: bash, redis-cli

How can I config redis-cli to use host and port for a certain bash script?
Something like:

```
redis-cli config host <host>
redis-cli config port <port>
```

is there way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a bash file to run this

```
redis-cli -h <<redis-host>> -p <<redis-port>>
```

Comment: there must be a redis-cli conf file maybe, so that I don't have to pass the host and port for every bash line?